# Unable to locate package ros-melodic-realsense2-camera

Tags: ros, package

I'm trying to install the realsense2-camera package for ROS Melodic, but I get this error message. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 .

Could anyone help me?

```
 sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-realsense2-camera

 Reading package lists... Done

 Building dependency tree 

 Reading state information... Done

 E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-realsense2-camera
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is an [answer to this question at answers.ros.org](https://answers.ros.org/question/356320/how-to-set-up-realsense_camera/) that says,

> Seems in melodic there are only realsense2 packages. If this is what you need, you can install it with:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-librealsense2 ros-melodic-realsense2-camera
> ```
>
> Otherwise, if you really need realsense instead of realsense2, you could clone the [repository](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/realsense-ros), choosing the "indigo-devel" branch, and build it with catkin. Though in this case you would need to build and install the librealsense binaries manually.